# Swift CoreData: error: Serious application error. Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, swift, core-data

I am writing one program on iOS and very race I am facing this error:

> 2015-11-06 10:57:24.289 NETFNET[2503:976392] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
>   2015-11-06 10:57:24.293 NETFNET[2503:976392] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'

I am trying to access Data Base simultaneously, I think, from main and background threads. I have seen a lot of solutions for Objective C, but none for Swift (I don't know Objective C...). Unfortunately, I don't know how to work with Grand Central Dispatch and, in fact, my program does not really need several treads (I mean it need it, but if some thread loses info from one function for one time, nothing bad will happen). I just want to have stable program on Swift 1 or 2, so I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: The vast majority of all iOS and OS X applications and libraries are written in ObjectiveC.  You should at least learn to read ObjectiveC, whether you can write functioning code with it or not.

Comment: @JodyHagins That' comment is not helpful at all.

Comment: Maybe... I just want to find a simple solution...

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a private NSManagedObjectContext with private queue concurrency type and use it to access CoreData whenever operating on a background thread.

So suppose I need to run a database operation on the background, I can dispatch that work to the background thread as

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {
        //call your background operation.
    })
```

Then in the background operation I can create a private NSManagedObjectContext as

```
let moc = … //Our primary context on the main queue

let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateMOC.parentContext = moc

privateMOC.performBlock {
    //operations
    do {
        try privateMOC.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Read through Apple's CoreData Concurrency Guide to get a good understanding before implementing core data operations on multiple threads.

Comment: Accessing to Data Base usually is going through Asynchronous connection to server (Post request, like this:

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(requestToServer, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        // Connection to data base
})

So is it not enough?

Comment: @MosTelecom No. that means your connection to db will be run asynchronously on a separate thread but you need to make sure that it doesn't use the main managed object context. that will help prevent simultaneous database access through the same moc.

Comment: @Alex i'm also facing same issue .Did you fixed this issue?, please let me know.i'm tried many ways but i can't able to fix this issue .

Comment: @Mohanaraj.C Look, one thing I can recommend to you is to upgrade your project to Swift 4.1 and rise minimum version of your app to iOS 10.0 because since this version in CoreData is available NSPersistentContainer. It will replace your current CoreDataStack and will allow you to avoid crashes.

Comment: @Alex currently i'm using swift 4.1 and minimum version app 10.0 but still i'm facing crash issue only for sometime. error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x60000045c9b0> was mutated while being enumerated. with userInfo (null)

Comment: @Mohanaraj.C Are you using NSPersistentContainer instead yours CoreDataStack? And are you working on new threads?

Comment: @Alex i'm using like this :class CoreDataManager {
    static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()
    private init(){}
        lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: “xxx")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Unresolved error 4 \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
            return container
    }()}

Comment: @Mohanaraj.C class CoreDataStack {
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "xxx")
        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
        }
        return container
    }()
    func saveContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
                
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Mohanaraj.C and later I created another class: class CoreDataFunctions {
    private let container = CoreDataStack().persistentContainer private func newThread(newThreadContext: ((NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void)?) {
        container.performBackgroundTask { newPrivateQueueContext in
            let newPrivateQueueContext = newPrivateQueueContext as NSManagedObjectContext
            newThreadContext?(newPrivateQueueContext)
        }
    } private func saveContext(newPrivateQueueContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
   CoreDataStack().saveContext(context: newPrivateQueueContext)}}

Comment: If you need to work with entity you should use only CoreDataFunctions class. You can write a functions to save or read, in fact it is very big class. But you have a basis. I am NOT sure that this is right approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176564/discussion-between-mohanaraj-c-and-alex).

Answer (score 6):

Very good. I tried it, it worked fine for me. 
Thank you very much.

Previous Code:

```
        do {
            try CDHelper.shared.context.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            // Error mesajlarını ekle!!
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.localizedFailureReason)")
        }


// MARK: - CONTEXT
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
    return moc
}()

// MARK: - MODEL
lazy var model: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL:self.modelURL)!
}()

// MARK: - COORDINATOR
lazy var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    return NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:self.model)
}()

lazy var modelURL: NSURL = {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    if let url = bundle.URLForResource("Model", withExtension: "momd") {
        return url
    }
    print("CRITICAL - Managed Object Model file not found")
    abort()
}()
```

you should change the code this way:

```
let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateMOC.parentContext = moc

privateMOC.performBlock({
    do {
        try privateMOC.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just calling your CoreData Function inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

...

}
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension for this and wrap the `save()` function to something like this so you'll just need to use this function instead of `save()`:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func update() throws {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = self

        context.perform({
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```